# Laravel multi level relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to create view that will show class_meets information
for additional information I want to show subject name from table subjects
already trying hasOneTrough, hasManyTrough and belongsToMany but it's like the function only show from subjects to class_meets, whereas what I need is the opposite

Want to add some function on ClassMeet Model

Here's from my Listing model:

- Subject

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public $table = 'subjects';
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'subject_name'
    ];
}
```

- Routine

```
class Routine extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public $table = 'routines';
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'academic_year_id',
        'subject_id',
        'classes_id'
        'day',
        'start_time',
        'end_time',
    ];
}
```

- ClassMeet

```
class ClassMeet extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public $table = 'class_meets';
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at', 'date'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'routine_id',
        'date'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hasOneTrough, hasManyTrough won't work in this case.

You need to add belongsTo relation to **ClassMeet**,**Routine**.

```
class ClassMeet extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public $table = 'class_meets';
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at', 'date'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'routine_id',
        'date'
    ];

    public routine(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Routine','routine_id','id')
    }
}
```

Routine Model be like

```
class Routine extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public $table = 'routines';
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'academic_year_id',
        'subject_id',
        'classes_id'
        'day',
        'start_time',
        'end_time',
    ];
     public subject(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject','subject_id','id')
     }
}
```

Now you can get the subject with routine.

```
ClassMeet::with('routine.subject')->get();
```